# Can I access two different dropboxes from one computer?

Tags: dropbox

We have a situation where a worker is using a Dropbox shared with many people in different companies to work on a collaborative project. She cannot figure out how to use our company's Dropbox now, to work on a different project. She needs access to both Dropboxes, at different times. We're using Windows 7. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

The steps to setup two Dropbox accounts on the same machine are as follows:

- Sign up, and setup dropbox for your business account
- Create an Automator app and add: `bash
  HOME=$HOME/Dropbox-personal /Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/MacOS/Dropbox &`

  - Where `Dropbox-personal` is the location of your personal Dropbox folder
- Save the script into your personal dropbox folder (for future use)
- OpenSystem Preferences > User Accounts, go to your login, and select `Login Items`

  - Add your application to the list of programs to launch at login

You can also change the app icons in your menu bar so that you can differentiate between the two accounts.

For more detailed instructions see [the original post](http://theterran.com/blog/2012/6/14/use-two-dropbox-accounts-on-one-computer.html)

Answer (score 2):

you can make use of the runas feature of windows.
for example you have 2 users on your windows, user1 and user2, user1 is the user you work with.
here's what you do.

```
1. login to user1, install dropbox
2. login to user2, install dropbox
3. back to user1, create a bat file with the following content: runas /user:user2 C:\Users\User2\AppData\Roaming\Dropbox\bin\Dropbox.exe
4. run dropbox on user1 as usual. then run this bat file, you'll be asked to type password of user2. then you have a second dropbox!
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tool that you can use.

http://www.bustatech.com/run-multiple-dropbox-on-your-pc-at-the-same-time/